# PowerBI extract value to table 2 based on multiple criteria from table 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a situation, the "Results Table" only have the entries as and when the event happened.  I need to have a view for all employees whether the requirement is completed or not (The HR requirement is all must have 1 health check and 2 review meetings for first half of year), therefore I created an "All Employee table", need help create the 'Health', 'Review 1' and 'Review 2' columns to extract values from the "Results table"?   Is this doable at all?

[image]

Comment: There will be always 1 health and 2 review for each employee? or they are dynamic?

Comment: Yes the requirement is 1 health and 2 reviews for every employee.  Not sure what i am picturing in my mind is doable or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 3 Measures for every Column:

```
Health = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date Completed]),'Table'[Type] = "Health")
Review 1 = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Date Completed]),'Table'[Type] = "Performance")
Review 2 = IF(CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date Completed]),'Table'[Type] = "Performance") = [Review 1],BLANK(),CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date Completed]),'Table'[Type] = "Performance"))
```

And then Create a table with the following Columns `EmployeeID`, and your 3 measures `Health`, `Review 1` and `Review 2`

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, I managed to create the measures to get what I needed, and also a couple others along like Completion status and % complete .

Answer (score 0):

If you can apply some transformation on your data in power query and use Matrix visual in the front end, number of column is not a big deal actually. For say you have this below data-

[image]

Here below the Power Query **steps/code** you need to apply on your data in the **Advanced Editor** of your table-

```
let
    ........,
    
    //New steps starts from here
    //update the previous_step_name accordingly in below line
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"previous_step_name", {"EmployeeID", "FormName"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [EmployeeID=nullable text, Type=nullable text, FormName=nullable text, DateCompleted=nullable date]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "rn", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"Index",1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"rn"}),
    #"Expanded rn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "rn", {"EmployeeID", "Type", "FormName", "DateCompleted", "Index"}, {"rn.EmployeeID", "rn.Type", "rn.FormName", "rn.DateCompleted", "rn.Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded rn",{{"rn.EmployeeID", "EmployeeID"}, {"rn.Type", "Type"}, {"rn.FormName", "FormName"}, {"rn.DateCompleted", "DateCompleted"}, {"rn.Index", "Index"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each if [FormName] = "Wellbeing" then "Health" else "Review"),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", each [Custom] &" "& Text.From([Index])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Type", "FormName", "Index", "Custom"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.1", "Category"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

Now you will have this below data-

[image]

Now just use a **Matrix** visual and the final output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: thanks for your time in my case, I took the easy out option by creating measures.  I am not a code person, but I will give it a try on your proposed to improve my knowledge.   thanks again.